# Are incorrect login attempts logged in by the website or company

Tags: security

When you put in an incorrect user id and/or password , do companies/websites keep a record of that?

Like for example Joe1 had an incorrect login attempt at this time?

And if so how long do they keep record of that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on security.se

Answer (score 4):

This is company dependent, normal security protocols would be 'yes', time could be unlimited it's just a log file. Mine has never been stopped or archived for years. I see what username they attempted with, ip address, the timestamp and the password they tried to use. This is a very basic log. Others are more intricate.

Comment: does It make it look suspicious if you keep clicking forgetting password?

Comment: Yes it does, certainly doesn't say anything positive anyway. Not an issue if it's something you rarely log in to. But it would catch my eye if someone was persistently having the issue on a system they use all the time. Depends what it is.

Comment: This is a good example of how services that don't store your passwords as plain text in the obvious place still end up storing your passwords as plain text in their logs. Don't reuse passwords folks.

Comment: @NathanCooper some do, some don't... mine are closed systems not publicly accessible, didn't bother getting too fancy. Some clients I set up don't store the password attempted, it's all down to the type of security you want to set up. These things are rarely done without putting a bit of thought into it. But I agree, DONT reuse passwords, it makes a single point of failure, never a good idea

Comment: Huh? Don’t reuse passwords? Are you saying that if you type in a wrong password on accident, you should change it?  Like do companies log the password that you put in incorrectly?

Comment: No, don't use the same password for all the different sites or apps, it means that if someone found out one password, they know them all... single point of failure... lots of people get caught out that way... someone gets their mail password, can access their facebook, other social media, internet banking, paypal etc,.

Comment: Thanks bro, I was wondering like when you type in. A wrong password, does the company or site or whatever the administrator or whoever is running the show, do they see the incorrect password you typed ?

Comment: Some do some don't, depends what they're trying to achieve with their security and what sort of system it is. Mine are closed financial systems, I actually assign the passwords so I know what they are. I'm interested in someone getting hold of a user id and trying to sign in, if the password is not a misspelling then it's someone trying to crack in and I'll investigate how they got hold of a legit user id (if it was) and ip and anything else and go through camera footage of the machine it came from once I've traced it

Comment: Isn’t that kinda risky Luke if someone types in a wrong password and they store it then someone sees it and it’s close to your actual password? I thought all passwords are encrypted

Comment: Depends on circumstances, if you can't understand, I can't help you further, explained clearly already.

Comment: You guys seem pretty tech savvy

Comment: So here’s a question Do smart phone apps listen to your in person convos? Like you know how you can give them access to your mic in settings like I was having a convo with a friend in person and my phone was beside me like does it listen in? I have Instagram and WhatsApp and both have permission to access the mic but only my Instagram was in the background

Comment: No idea, I have a very basic phone and just use it to ring people and answer calls.